An incomplete grid
The task is to complete the grid below by placing the correct figure in the bottom left cell. Explain why it's correct and...



...BTW try your hardest to solve it and stop only if you can't continue.

The missing figure is:

 

 i.e. If you envisage the 8 segments as points of a compass, colour the North segment blue, the North-east segment light blue, and the East segment red.

My choice of terminology here is no accident...

 Because with this symbol in place, you can draw straight lines joining all segments of the same colour to trace out letters of the alphabet. For each coloured segment, draw a straight line starting from the centre dot of its symbol and extend it in the compass direction in which it points until you reach either (i) another symbol of this colour or (ii) the last symbol at the far edge of the image.

 Specifically, you trace out letters that can be ordered to spell the appropriate word CARDINALS - apt since this puzzle makes use of the eight cardinal directions (the points of the compass)!




Damn.  I had the missing figure, but I couldn't figure out the word because I thought the small A was a P.

You got it, good job!
